# Scroll to top and title service is not working parallel in angular 6

Tags: angular, routes, angular6

```
this.document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = function() {
            return false;
        };

    /* Activated change detection for the title change */
    this.router.events
        .filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationEnd)
        .map(() => this.activatedRoute)
        .map((route) => {
            while (route.firstChild) {
                route = route.firstChild;
            }
            return route;
        })
        .filter((route) => route.outlet === 'primary')
        .mergeMap((route) => route.data)
        .subscribe((event) => {
            this.titleService.setTitle(event['title']);
            this.metaService.addTag(event['meta']);
        });
```

I am using the router to update the title and metadata using title service in app component

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: './main/pages/pages.module#PagesModule',
        data: {
            title: 'Home Page',
            meta: {name: 'description', content: 'hello its home'}
        }
    },
    {
        path: '**',
        redirectTo: '/you-know-nothing-jon-snow'
    }
];
```

Also I need to use the scroll to top for few dynamic url pages to scroll to top on each click. If I remove the routeReuseStrategy the setTitle works and set the title using router, both does not work together, I tied other options but none working as expected for either one of them for the application.
Is there a way to make them work together ?

Comment: When you say "it's not working", can you be more specific please? What is the expected behaviour? What is the actual behaviour? Are you able to create a StackBlitz that reproduces the problem?

Comment: scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled',https://medium.com/lacolaco-blog/introduce-router-scroller-in-angular-v6-1-ef34278461e9

Answer (score 0):

It's a hack, but you can try using `setTimeout`:

```
.subscribe((event) => {
        this.titleService.setTitle(event['title']);
        this.metaService.addTag(event['meta']);
        setTimeout(() => this.document.body.scrollTop = 0);
    });
```

BTW, you can also use `window.scrollTo` to animate the scroll (might also solve your problem)

```
window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: "smooth" });
```

Comment: I am able to scroll to top on route change however if route param changes it does not scroll to top on same router outlet and only routeReuseStrategy is working in that case, however it comes up with the cost of title service not working as expected.